# How geckobrowser span button skip innertext click?

Tags: webbrowser-control, geckodriver, gecko, geckofx

geckowebbrowser span button skip need clicked

I'm trying hard to click the span button but it's not clicking at all. Span A class comes randomly so I can't do class dia. I have given the code below if any expert can help me.

```
  <span jsname="V67aGc" class="VfPpkd-vQzf8d">Skip</span>
```

I am try below code but it's show not working!!!

```
 foreach (HtmlElement els in geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span"))
        {
            if (els.InnerText == ("Skip"))
            {
                els.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextContent` instead of `InnerText`.

```
foreach (GeckoHtmlElement els in geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span"))
{
    if (els.TextContent.Trim() == "Skip")
    {
        els.Click();
        break;
    }
}
```